# Como selecionar exatamente o elemento buscado no jQuery independente de classes ou ids?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Se executarem o código verão que o segundo formulário é influenciado pelo primeiro e não pega os dados referente a ele próprio. Claro que isso é uma falha no meu jQuery. O primeiro formulário funciona perfeitamente, já o segundo pega sempre o último valor enviado pelo primeiro.

Eu preciso que cada um envie seus dados independente da classe `estado` se repetir nos dois formulários. Esta informação é posteriormente enviada para um Ajax que fará uma consulta no banco de dados.

Estes formulários dividem a mesma página e tem as mesmas classes trocando simplesmente o id do formulário. O que parece é que ele sempre executa o formulário que vier primeiro e depois para de executar justamente pelo fato dos selects terem a mesma classe.

Podem me ajudar?

```js
function buscar_cidades(e){
 
  var formid = $(e).closest("form").attr("id");
  var estado = $(".estado").val();
  
  alert(estado);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="fpf" class="" method="post" action="">
  <select name="estado" class="estado" onchange="buscar_cidades(this)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="000001">AC</option>
    <option value="000002">AL</option>
    <option value="000003">AM</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form id="fpj" class="" method="post" action="">
  <select name="estado" class="estado" onchange="buscar_cidades(this)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="000001">AC</option>
    <option value="000002">AL</option>
    <option value="000003">AM</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Tu estás a ir buscar o valor selecionado pelo name... Visto que tens duas select com o mesmo nome, vai dar buraco. Tens de ir buscar a select pertencente ao form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na tua função deves referir-te ao elemento que recebeste e não localizar o mesmo pela classe de CSS:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/7y1m6vyy/)

```
function buscar_cidades(e){

  var formid = $(e).closest("form").attr("id");
  var estado = $(e).find('option:selected').val();

  alert(estado);
}
```

De igual forma podes otimizar a função para evitar sucessivas pesquisas no DOM por parte do jQuery:

```
function buscar_cidades(meuSelect){
  var $this  = $(meuSelect),
      formId = $this.closest("form").attr("id"),
      estado = $this.find('option:selected').val();

  alert(estado);
}
```

**Nota:** Já referido na resposta do @Sergio, tens que ter em conta que ao usar a classe de CSS para localizar o elemento, o que é devolvido é o primeiro elemento do DOM que contém essa classe, motivo o qual o valor que o teu `alert()` dá é sempre o mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

Quando usa um seletor como `var estado = $(".estado").val();` ele vai sempre pegar o primeiro valor encontrado, mesmo que haja mais no DOM.

O que precisa é usar assim, visto que a sua função já passa o "elemento certo":

```
var estado = $(e).val(); // ou mesmo somente e.value
```

```js
function buscar_cidades(e){
 
  var formid = $(e).closest("form").attr("id");
  var estado = $(e).val();
  
  alert(estado);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="fpf" class="" method="post" action="">
  <select name="estado" class="estado" onchange="buscar_cidades(this)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="000001">AC</option>
    <option value="000002">AL</option>
    <option value="000003">AM</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form id="fpj" class="" method="post" action="">
  <select name="estado" class="estado" onchange="buscar_cidades(this)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="000001">AC</option>
    <option value="000002">AL</option>
    <option value="000003">AM</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Na verdade isto podia ser feito sem jQuery:

```
function buscar_cidades(e) {
    var formid = e.form.id;
    var estado = e.value;
    alert(formid + ' - ' + estado);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yqay7mk2/

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta sempre pertinente e completíssima.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Esta devia ser a resposta aceite dado estar mais completa e ter sido colocada primeiro ;)